# HttpHandler implementation

Tags: asp.net, web-config, httphandler

I have implemented a custom HttpHandler for my website which will redirect the page to a specific page if the page is in a list. So far the redirection is working fine but the issue is the content of the final page goes blank.

Code From My PageHandler:

```
public class CustomPageHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
        fileList.Add("Page1.aspx");
        fileList.Add("Page2.aspx");

        foreach (string fileName in fileList)
        {
            if (context.Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Contains(fileName.ToLower()))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("BlockedPage.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code from my Web.Config file [Related to HttpHandler]

```
<httpHandlers>
   .
   .
   .
   <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="CustomPageHandler, App_Code"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Anyone can help me to get out of this sticky situation? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @AntonioBakula nope, I can't use .ashx its a .cs file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. An HttpHandler is what actually processes the request. Your code does nothing if the request is not a request to one of the pages in the list. That's why there is no output.

If you want to *modify* the processing of pages instead of *replacing* it, then you need an HttpModule.